# Access Query UPCOMING EXPIRATION DATES

Tags: ms-access

How can I run a query to see upcoming expiration dates in Access without seeing expiration dates that have already passed?

Comment: Your question would be clearer if you were to add more information pertaining to the structure & content of your database tables.

Comment: Please also include what you have already tried and the resources you have come across that you think might be pertinent to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Construct a query whose criteria compares the value of the field containing your "expiration date" with the current date as returned by `Date()`, selecting those records whose "expiration date" is greater than or equal to `Date()`.

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE myTable.ExpirationDate >= Date()
```